# firefox.exe - Bad image

Tags: windows-7, script

When I open any program it gives me an error. For example, when I want to run Firefox, Windows gives me the following error:

[image]

How can I remove this error ? When I want to run other programs it gives me the same error. I am using Windows 7 64 bit.

I didn't notice any xifs virus. Please tell what can I do.

Comment: Hi, did you do any change before that error appear ? (Windows update, etc ?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: No I didn;t do any change @ob1lan . I can't see any xifs virus .

Comment: You can't ... while it's telling you that it's including a DLL that is not part of Firefox and indeed points to that particular virus/malware? Did you actually follow the steps in either of the linked resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a malware which is found in my PC . I have removed this malware in the following way :

```
1. I have started PC in safe mode . 
2 . I have removed these two folders : xif and xifs from C:/programData folder .
```

Then the xifs malware is removed .